# Meaning of で in: 来月私たちのダンスの発表会があります。是非皆さんで見に来てほしいです。

Tags: meaning, particle-で

> 来月私たちのダンスの発表会があります。是非皆さんで見に来てほしいです。
> Next month we have a dance meeting. I want everyone to come and see it.

Can someone explain what the で in this sentence means?
It is not the continuative form (連用形) of the assertive auxiliary (断定の助動詞), or "copula", だ/です so what is it?
It is not the AT で. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a good duplicate, so I started writing up an answer. I was halfway into composing this when a duplicate was suggested. After reading that answer, I think I'd like to add something of my own, at the end.

This 助詞 で can be found [here](https://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A7):

> 7. 主体を表す。
>    こちらでやっておきます。
>    クラスのみんなで山に登った。

So this で is used to indicate the agent of the action. As mentioned in the linked answer, this is another way of seeing で as marking "how". It specifies how something happens, with the emphasis on the entity marked by で as a whole.

> 来年もこのメンツで花見に行こう
> Next year, we (people who showed up today/last time) shall go see cherry blossoms.

In such sentences the noun marked by で is usually the agent of the action. Your sentence thus can be understood to have 皆さんが omitted

> 是非(皆さんが)皆さんで見に来てほしいです。

Comment: The so-called duplicate is asking "Why is で used instead of と". But this question is a study on "で". They may be related but not a duplicate, and this answer by Eddie Kal is more appropriate for this question.